# Unable to deserialize MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap.

The MultivaluedHashMap implements java.io.Serializable and has a public, no arg constructor.

However when deserializing a previously serialized MultivaluedHashMap, an InvalidClassException, no valid constructor, is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap; no valid constructor
>       at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:231)
>       at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:267)
>       at org.arx.serializationtest.Main.main(Main.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap; no valid constructor
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:150)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:768)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>       at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:223)
>       ... 7 more

This is easily reproduced by running the simple 3 lines long main method below:

```
package test;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
        byte[] serializedMap = SerializationUtils.serialize(map);

        MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> deserializedMap = SerializationUtils.deserialize(serializedMap);
    }
}
```

From there I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Any suggestion or pointer would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one of the classes that is needed for deserializeing `MultivaluedHashMap` doesn't have a parameterless constructor. You can do something like this:

```
MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> serMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(map);
byte[] serializedMap = SerializationUtils.serialize(serMap);

HashMap<String, List<String>> tempMap = SerializationUtils.deserialize(serializedMap);
MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> deserializedMap = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : tempMap.entrySet()) {
    deserializedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

What this does is to create a `HashMap` which will hold all the values needed to reconstruct the original `MultivaluedHashMap` and serialize/deserialize this `HashMap` instead of the `MultivaluedHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks Titus, I replaced the MultivaluedHashMap with a Map<String, List<String>> to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because MultivaluedHashMap does not implement Serializable. To solve this do the following:

```js
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;

public class MyMultivaluedHashMap<K, V> extends MultivaluedHashMap<K, V> implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 public MyMultivaluedHashMap(){
  super();
  //there are other contruc super class
 }
}

//your code
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;

public class Teste{
    public Teste(){}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        MyMultivaluedHashMap<String, String> map = new MyMultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
        map.addFirst("key-1", "chubby");
        map.add("key-2", "skinny");
        byte[] serializedMap = SerializationUtils.serialize(map);
        System.out.println(serializedMap);
        MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> deserializedMap = SerializationUtils.deserialize(serializedMap);
        System.out.println(deserializedMap);
    }
}
```

So you just create a new class, MyMultivaluedHashMap, that implements Serializable.

Comment: Actually `MultivaluedHashMap` implements `Serializable` you can see that in [this calss' java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedHashMap.html)

Comment: Ok, if your version implement Serializable, but i'm see one version not was implementation.

Comment: Thanks @MarceloFerreira, although Titus is right, the recent version of MultivaluedHashMap implements Serializable.